# why this screen, while app opens every time

Tags: android

Here I am getting this screen every time just like a splash for few seconds and then opening the home activity.I don't want to this screen in my app.  How to fix it.

[image]

Here is my manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.asdf.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For your Information, I am using Support Library for developing.

I changed the app Style to **"@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"** then this screen is not showing but It has the impact on other UI components of the same App like.. Spinner, text-view etc.

Comment: Maybe you do some heavy works in UT that's the reason of blank screen display.

Comment: I have also tested the hello world app. getting the same screen with "Hello world" as the title in place of "ZOO"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in your style.xml

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

try this..well previous one should work.It worked for me

Comment: yes after adding this line to style.xml, I didn't see any such screen but getting blank screen for 1 or 2  secs and then displaying the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the title bar, then use the following in your Activity initialization:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

move Intent-filter code to whichever activity of your application. and remove that activity code.

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Hope it will work